# replicate iPhone like navigation bar - layout alignment in android

Tags: android, android-layout

There are three views in my layout (button textview button) and the buttons visibility may change( Invisible/Gone, whatever makes implementing this possible).

The image attached explains my problem, please have a look.

What I'm trying to do is implement the logic which the iPhone navigation bar follows, but i cant seem to get it working.

[image]

What i have tried :

- Linear layouts, with all permutations of weights & gravity
- relative layout with assigning parentCenterHorizontal to the middle text view, parentLeft and parentRight to the left and right buttons - By doing this the views overlap each other, when extended. rather than making them shift. If i use the the toLeftOf or toRightOf attributes, it overrides the parentCenter/parentLeft/parentRight tags, which makes this approach useless.

Comment: What style is the parent layout? LinearLayout, RelativeLayout?

Comment: I think it is better to use [Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html). In my own experience in iPhone I found NaviagationBar very close to AcionBar in Android.

Comment: @RyanInBinary whatever can get the job done. I have tried every possible think i could think of and search around in both of them. Turns out the priority of "toRightOf" is more than "center horizontal parent" attribute, so that didnt work for me.

Comment: @Ali - I can't use action bar, i'll have to rewrite a huge amount of code in the app to make that change. Thanks anyway.

Comment: post the code that you used when you got the "what I could achieve" outcome.

Comment: @Tim - i tried what RyanInBinary posted below. I also tried the relative layout ( read my comment above), and all other obvious solutions. I can't believe something which sounds this simple has got me stumped.